# How do you remove multiple nbsp from your website

Tags: html

I have just pasted the content from ms word to my blog page and I found there is a lot of space in the blog edit section and that because of `&nbsp;`. How do I remove them in one click.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe via Search and Replace? Replace `"&nbsp;"` with a space and after that replace all double-spaces with single spaces ... multiple times. Until there's nothing to replace.

Comment: This is the best way to go. To expand on that, I use SublimeText (free) for simple code based find and replace, because it's find and replace tool is quick and powerful. You can do a regex search with it and replace with \s. Personally I find 8 &nbsp;, and replace with one \s. Then 7, then 6, etc. In this way you remove the long breaks with short ones.